# Does the phrase of "I love when" is considered normal in English?

Tags: phrases

When I want to show my love to something that is done by someone, can I say

> "**I love when** you wear belt / when you sing / when you talk
>   quietly."

Does I have to add some word (maybe pronoun like "you" in this case) after "I love" and before "when"?

Answer (score 2):

There's an invisible 'object' reference in "I love when..."

> I love **it** when...

re-adds the missing object.

Either is acceptable for colloquial speech.
I wouldn't ever use it in formal writing.

It's a simple contraction of the full idea, "I love that you [do this] when you [do this]"
which, of course, no-one would ever say in full.

Comment: Thank you for your answer +1^. Anyway, You intrigued me by your statement "I wouldn't ever use it in formal writing". Can you tell me the alternative/s?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that there's any more of a "missing object" in OP's construction than there is in, say, *I love what you're wearing, I appreciate what you're saying, We know where you live,* etc. The fact that in some of those constructions you *could* introduce an article doesn't necessarily imply that it's "missing" if you didn't include it.

Comment: You couldn't squeeze **it** into any of those constructions with a large crowbar. The 'implied it' in 'I love when' is an entirely different case. Were I more accomplished at actual grammar/linguistics rather than being merely being a competent native speaker, I'd be happy to quote chapter & verse - however, as I'm not... it's only my opinion ;) "I love when..." "You love **what** when?" I love... ermm... **it**"

Answer (score 0):

I have heard both forms used, and have no particular preference for one or the other, however, you do require an indefinite article before "belt". So you can say:

> I love when you wear a belt/ when you sing/ when you talk quietly.

or

> I love it when you wear a belt/ when you sing/ when you talk quietly.